# Html table width

Tags: css, html

I have a html table which is going out of page border if the table body conent is large.
When I set the width to 100% , still it is not fitting into the screen.

How to make the table to fit to  screen.

```
<table width="100%">
```

The above code is not working if table body is large than the screen size

Comment: A JFiddel would help, mayebe it's in the wrong div.

Comment: Don't use HTML attribute to style `<table>`; use CSS instead.

Comment: by default words in paragraph should wrap automatically. Please provide example contents in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put content in the cells which can't word wrap sufficiently to allow all the cells to be narrow enough for the table to fit in the space allocated to it.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set the table layout to *fixed* in CSS.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85eSX/).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget tempor ligula, non ultricies lacus. Cras sed sapien nec tortor porttitor ornare quis et erat. Nunc molestie sodales sem, in volutpat leo ultrices sed. Ut vel orci magna. Nulla vitae mi venenatis, auctor nulla et, rutrum nibh. Phasellus sollicitudin, purus vitae mollis pretium, nibh leo ullamcorper ligula, vel porta libero metus nec mauris. Pellentesque quis tellus dui. Duis id justo libero. Fusce sagittis, metus ut vestibulum ullamcorper, ligula urna vulputate ipsum, vel condimentum orci enim nec nulla. Fusce viverra metus at porta suscipit. Praesent suscipit blandit cursus. Nulla dignissim sodales posuere. Etiam posuere porta sem.

Donec commodo ut est sit amet blandit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse non felis id nunc bibendum consequat ut quis orci. Ut mattis purus mi, quis dictum risus sollicitudin at. Pellentesque eu molestie metus. Donec aliquet nulla tellus, non rhoncus velit convallis imperdiet. Nam vitae ullamcorper nisi, ut condimentum eros.

Etiam mollis, augue quis suscipit cursus, mauris risus mollis tellus, sit amet tincidunt augue eros sed erat. Fusce mattis erat nec est molestie, at sodales nisl posuere. Nam quis tellus nisi. Proin pharetra sapien nec blandit sollicitudin. Donec et leo egestas, accumsan eros non, scelerisque magna. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi porta molestie diam, id mattis nisl suscipit sit amet. Suspendisse iaculis erat vel venenatis eleifend. Ut ipsum urna, vulputate vitae lacus vitae, aliquam adipiscing nisi. Sed molestie bibendum pretium. Morbi vel rutrum nulla, nec luctus elit. Nunc interdum aliquet adipiscing. Nam purus nisl, mollis nec porttitor et, mattis ut ipsum. Aliquam fermentum tristique tellus, aliquam mollis est pulvinar non. Nam cursus risus orci, non euismod nisl vestibulum pretium.

Nulla eleifend lacus eu eleifend consequat. Morbi dapibus diam in laoreet ullamcorper. Nulla commodo quam nisl, lacinia adipiscing purus mollis et. Ut eleifend aliquam felis sollicitudin congue. Nam facilisis lacus erat, a consequat eros laoreet nec. Mauris consequat sodales nulla sed accumsan. Maecenas condimentum ullamcorper felis, non aliquam lorem interdum vel. Nulla facilisi. In vehicula eros sit amet nulla lacinia malesuada eget sed neque. Sed ante mauris, ultrices vel tempus sit amet, aliquet in enim.

Fusce ultrices dui enim, id aliquam diam placerat non. Donec volutpat interdum nisl et rutrum. In vulputate porttitor nunc ac luctus. Mauris non vulputate nibh. Etiam ut lorem quis sem semper ultrices. Sed varius nunc ac eleifend hendrerit. Nam in vehicula nunc. Nulla ac diam ac magna malesuada facilisis in lobortis lacus. Cras cursus nec erat eget cursus. Maecenas ac mauris non augue vehicula porta et viverra sapien. Suspendisse consequat eu sapien vel sollicitudin. Morbi mollis sollicitudin hendrerit. Donec eu cursus mauris.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see, the cell contains a lot of text that I prevented from wrapping. The table is set to 100% width but without fixed layout, it still take as much width as it needs to fit its largest cell.

With fixed layout, it will remain 100% wide, whatever happens within its cells.

Try to comment and uncomment the following line in the stylesheet declaration, to witness the difference :

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

Comment: `word-wrap` CSS may help too.